# how to fetch from PROCEDURE call in joomla

Tags: stored-procedures, joomla

I am working in joomla. And I have huge amount of data in mySql table. I need a calculation for the project with all this data. As the result will vary every time, I am using MySql PROCEDURE to execute the calculation.

In the PROCEDURE I am first working the calculation, then inserting the data in a temporary table (tmp_zipcode), then fetching it. Its all working fine. But I need to fetch it directly after calculation. I do not want to insert the data to temporary table then fetch it every time.

The following is a procedure call in mySql. However, I think, you don't need to go through below whole PROCEDURE code to answer this question.

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP   FUNCTION  IF EXISTS `GetDistance`$$ 

CREATE   FUNCTION  `GetDistance`( 
 lat1  numeric (9,6), 
 lon1  numeric (9,6), 
 lat2  numeric (9,6), 
 lon2  numeric (9,6) 
)  RETURNS   decimal (10,5) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE  x  decimal (20,10); 
  DECLARE  pi  decimal (21,20); 
  SET  pi = 3.14159265358979323846; 
  SET  x = sin( lat1 * pi/180 ) * sin( lat2 * pi/180  ) + cos( 
 lat1 *pi/180 ) * cos( lat2 * pi/180 ) * cos(  abs ( (lon2 * pi/180) - 
 (lon1 *pi/180) ) ); 
  SET  x = atan( ( sqrt( 1- power( x, 2 ) ) ) / x ); 
  RETURN  ( 1.852 * 60.0 * ((x/pi)*180) ) / 1.609344; 
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$ 

DROP   PROCEDURE  IF EXISTS `GetNearbyZipCodes`$$ 

CREATE   PROCEDURE  `GetNearbyZipCodes`( 
    zipbase  varchar (6), 
    rang  numeric (15) 
) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE  lat1  decimal (5,2); 
DECLARE  long1  decimal (5,2); 
DECLARE  rangeFactor  decimal (7,6); 
SET  rangeFactor = 0.014457; 
SELECT  Latitude,Longitude  into  lat1,long1  FROM   ZIPCodes  WHERE  ZipCode = zipbase; 
Insert into tmp_zipcode(zipcode,radius) SELECT B.ZipCode,GetDistance(lat1,long1,B.Latitude,B.Longitude) FROM  ZIPCodes  AS  B WHERE B.Latitude  BETWEEN  lat1-(rang*rangeFactor) AND lat1+(rang*rangeFactor) AND  B.Longitude  BETWEEN  long1-(rang*rangeFactor)  AND  long1+(rang*rangeFactor) AND  GetDistance(lat1,long1,B.Latitude,B.Longitude) <= rang; 
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

The following is joomla code which I am using to call the PROCEDURE. Here first I am truncating the temp table and then calling the PROCEDURE in which it inserts data. Then I fetch it again.

```
$truncate="truncate table tmp_zipcode";
$db->setquery($truncate);
$db->query();

$test="CALL GetNearbyZipCodes( $zipcode ,$miles)";
$db->setquery($test);
$re=$db->query();
$result_codes_query="select zipcode,radius from tmp_zipcode";
$db->setquery($result_codes_query);
$db->query();
$codes=$db->loadAssocList();
```

So I need to fetch the calculation part directly, without inserting to, and fetching from temp table. I do not want to use a temp table at all. How I can fetch data from MySql PROCEDURE in joomla ?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting when calling the procedure?

Comment: First you should stop using deprecated methods like query() and try using the API more, it will really help. Why is it that you used a temporary table to start with?  What is $re? Why are you not just loading the results from the select in the stored procedure right when it happens instead of doing the two step thing?